# See HTTPS-POST values from my browser

Tags: http, post

I would like to see the HTTPS-POST sent from my browser via secure HTTPS (so no wireshark'ing).

I would like to see what happens when I send the submit on a form.  Any ideas how to do this?

Example I'd like to see the resulting https-post of a submit:

```
https://somewebsite_i_am_viewing_on_my_pc.com/something.do?value1=xyz&value2=qwe
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebug for Firefox.

http://getfirebug.com/

http://getfirebug.com/network

Chrome Developer Tools for Chrome.

http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/network.html

Internet Explorer 9 Developer Tools for IE9.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg130952%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

If you want to use Fiddler, you have to follow these instructions to enable HTTPS traffic decryption:
http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp

Comment: Post is out of date

Answer (score 0):

**matthewk** point you some tools. I also suggest [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), it is more general tool to watch you network activity